# How to restrict routes to user profiles while allowing an admin user to access all routes in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

In my application I created the access according to the profile of each user.

The admin user only has access to the `admin.vue` page.

What I want is for the admin user to have access to all pages of the application.

The router's `index.js` in my application looks like this:

```
if (userAuth) {
  firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdTokenResult()
    .then(function ({
      claims
    }) {

if (claims.customer) {
  if (to.path !== '/customer')
   return next({
    path: '/customer',
   })
  } else if (claims.admin) {
  if (to.path !== '/admin')
   return next({
    path: '/admin',
   })
  } else if (claims.driver) {
if (to.path !== '/driver')
  return next({
   path: '/driver',
  })
 }  
})
}
```

But in this way the admin only has access to the `admin.vu`e page, but I intend that he also has access to 
the `customer.vue` and `driver.vue` page.

I tried on `else if (claims.admin) {` two hypotheses, but they didn't work:

1st hypothesis:

```
else if (claims.admin) {
   next({
    path: '/customer',
    path: '/driver'            
    path: '/admin',
   })
}
```

2nd hypothesis:

```
else if (claims.admin) {
  next({
    path: '/customer',
  })
}
```

With these two hypotheses the result is that when I login with admin, it goes to the `admin.vue` page, when I try to enter one of the other pages it always stays on the `admin.vue` page, it does not forward to the other pages.

Do I have any way for the admin to have access to all pages?

Comment: You can register global before guards using `router.beforeEach`. I think registering this globally will solve issue at initial check. 
And you can write like
 if (claims.admin) {
  nex()
}

Comment: @Abhishek Shastri I don't know if I understood, I updated the code in the question with my complete code. I think what you suggested already exists in my code, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try after replacing this code `if (claims.admin) {
  if (to.path !== '/admin')
   return next({
    path: '/admin',
   })
  }`  with  `if (claims.admin) {
   return next()
  }`

Comment: @Abhishek Shastri This is how it works, but when you log in as admin, that way you don't forward to any of the pages. I intended that when logging in, forward to the admin.vue page.

Comment: Keep a check for `to.path` availability with required value. If present then return `next` otherwise send that to `/admin`.

Comment: @Abhishek Shastri But if you do it the way you're saying, isn't it the same as it was before? That way afterwards I don't have access to all the pages. What I wanted was to have access to all the pages, but when you login with admin, forward to the folder admin.vue